# Flexbox responsive layout with multiple sidebars

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Is there any way with flexbox to have 5 elements, 4 of which are `75%` container width, then item 4 is `25%` and displays as sidebar?

Ultimately I want to take item 3 and turn it into a 2nd sidebar as well.

mobile

```
|_container 1_|
|_container 2_|
|_container 3_|
|___sidebar___|
|_container 4_|
```

desktop

```
|_container 1_|_sidebar_|
|_container 2_|         |
|_container 3_|         |
|_container 4_|         |
```

large desktop

```
|_container 1_|_container 4_|_sidebar_|
|_container 2_|             |         |
|_container 3_|             |         |
```

Comment: I'm sure there is but SO guidelines suggest that you attempt it yourself first and we can assist with anything you can't get quite right. Try making an [**example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my attempt to achieve the layout via **[Flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox)**, in the example below resize the output panel to see the effect:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/wjHos)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item container-1">Container 1</div>

  <div class="wrapper group">
    <div class="item container-2">Container 2</div>
    <div class="item container-3">Container 3</div>
  </div>

  <aside class="item sidebar">Sidebar</aside>
  <div class="item container-4">Container 4</div>
</div>
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.wrapper { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; }
.item { text-align: center; padding: .3em; }
.group, .item { flex: 1 100%; }

/* Medium devices */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item { flex: 0 75%; }
  .container-1 { order: -2; flex: 1 auto; }
  .sidebar { order: -1; flex: 0 25%; }
}

/* Large devices */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .item { flex: 1 50%; }
  .container-1 { order: -3; flex: 1 auto; }
  .container-4 { order: -2; flex: 0 25%; }
  .sidebar { order: -1; flex: 0 25%; }
  .group { flex: 0 50%; }
}
```

**Note:** Vendor prefixes are needed to support earlier versions of web browsers such as IE10 *(but not as old as IE9!)*. I used [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) in the **[demo](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/wjHos)** (Thanks to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/)!). If you click on *"Toggle Compiled View"*, you'll see the prefixed version of CSS declarations.

You might also want to change the breakpoints of `@media` queries to fit your needs.

At last but not least, if you're not familiar with [CSS Flexible Box Layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox) you could refer to the following resources:

- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox *(The spec is your friend!)*
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/

Comment: How could the sidebars be made full-height?